# How can I run a NuGet Package Manager command on solution build in visual studio

Tags: build, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I am using MvcCodeRouting in my ASP.NET MVC web application.
To embed the views from assemblies into my main website project I use the following command into the NuGet Package Manager Console `Extract-Views AssemblyName AssemblyFolder`
I don't want to do this every time I change or add an assembly. I want to just press build and if the whole build is successful I want Visual Studio to automatically run the command for me.

Is there a way Visual Studio can do this?